# C++ error : Expected an identifier

Tags: c++, long-integer, identifier, specifier

i am trying to make an header but it gives me error :

```
#ifndef __OFFSETS__H_
#define __OFFSETS__H_

typedef unsigned long MAIN = 0x22EA120;//0x022BF0C0 ;
typedef unsigned long RECOILVT = 0x020A3ACC;//0x020FA644;
typedef unsigned long DEVIATIONVT = 0x020A3AC8;//0x020FA640;

#define BF3_X                       
#define BF3_X_BASE                  
#define BF3_X_SIZE                  
#define OFFSET_CLIENTGAMECONTEXT    
#define OFFSET_BORDERINPUTNODE      
#define OFFSET_DXRENDERER           
#define OFFSET_GAMERENDERER         
#define pbcl_BASE                   
#define OFFSET_PBSS_BUFFER          
#define OFFSET_PBSS_TAKESS                 
#define OFFSET_GIVEDAMAGE           Address
#define OFFSET_COMPUTEAAB           0x010C95F0 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA       
#define OFFSET_AABWORLDTRANSFORM    0x010C6610 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA Address
#define OFFSET_DBGRENDERER2         0x00000000 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA 
#define OFFSET_DBGRENDRAWTEXT       0x004B7610 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA   
#define OFFSET_DBGRENDRAW2DLINE     0x004B9980 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA 
#define OFFSET_DBGRENDRAWRECTLINE   0x004A11E0 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA Address
#define OFFSET_DBGRENDRAWRECT           
#define OFFSET_DBGRENDRAWSPHERE     0x004B7610 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA 
#define OFFSET_UPDATEMATRICES       0x006C3A90 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA     
#define OFFSET_W2S                  0x00EF1590 // Function - BF3_X_BASE 
#define OFFSET_RS_BEGINDRAW         0x006800A1 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA 
#define OFFSET_CLIENTPLAYER_ENTRY   0x00A99A20 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA Address
#define OFFSET_CSW_GETWEAPON        0x01049B60 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA 
#define OFFSET_CSW_GETHEAT          0x00000000 // Function - BF3_X_BASE = IDA 
#endif
```

the error is

```
error C2513: 'unsigned long' : no variable declared before '='
```

and i don't know why ? any idea ?

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: You should probably take out yor fine introductory book and read about typedefs, macros, and variables.

Answer (score 3):

These lines are incorrect

```
typedef unsigned long MAIN = 0x22EA120;//0x022BF0C0 ;
typedef unsigned long RECOILVT = 0x020A3ACC;//0x020FA644;
typedef unsigned long DEVIATIONVT = 0x020A3AC8;//0x020FA640;
```

You are defining a type. You cannot give a type a value.

Do one or the other!

**EDIT**

Either

a)

```
typedef unsigned long MAIN;
typedef unsigned long RECOILVT;
typedef unsigned long DEVIATIONVT;
```

or

b)

```
#define MAIN 0x22EA120
#define RECOILVT 0x020A3ACC
#define DEVIATIONVT 0x020A3AC8
```

or

c)

```
const int MAIN = 0x22EA120;//0x022BF0C0 ;
const int RECOILVT = 0x020A3ACC;//0x020FA644;
const int DEVIATIONVT = 0x020A3AC8;//0x020FA640;
```

Your choice

Comment: i changed it to DWORD and it gave me no error i think thats correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `typedef unsigned long MAIN = 0x22EA120;` to be `const unsigned long MAIN = 0x22EA120;//0x022BF0C0 ;` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, we'te both guessing. When I wrote my reply, you didn't have a "solution", so I thought I'd provide something that solves the problem - because I think that's what the OP wanted to do.